# Is [Install] section obligatory for autostart services in systemd?

Tags: systemd

I am reading https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html and can not find information if `[Install]` section is required for service autostart.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The standard way to make some program executed on startup with `systemd` is to create `.service` file for it, place that file into [corresponding directory](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Unit%20File%20Load%20Path) and run `systemctl enable <service>` to **enable** it for startup sequence. `[Install]` section is mandatory here, because it tells `systemd` at which moment during boot process your service should be started. You process **should be** linked to some [generic boot targets](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd#Mapping_between_SysV_runlevels_and_systemd_targets) such as `multi-user.target` or `graphical.target`, or to a special purpose target (such as `network-online.target`), or a custom local target.

Example:

```
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here `systemd` will inject your service as a dependency for `multi-user.target`. `systemd` will start your service whenever `multi-user` target is started.

systemd reads files (or symlinks) in its configuration directories to see which units should be started in what order. `systemctl enable` creates such symlinks for services that it already knows, and places these symlinks at the points at the boot process when the service should be started (e.g. in special `multi-user.target.wants/` subdirectory.)

---

There is also another way how operating system uses `systemd` to start its own services at startup. It is not something that should you do, but since the question is about `[Install]` section...

There are `systemd` units called "static" units and they are not managed by `systemctl enable` (or `systemctl disable`.) They are started on boot through hardcoded symlinks in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/` (instead of `/etc/systemd/system/`), and if you encounter them while looking at units in your system... know that they don't have `[Install]` section.

(You can see [the discussion in this forum post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=147964) for even more details on static units.)

Comment: OMG. That's surely confusing! I thought there is only one way to autostart `systemd` services. That is - with `systemctl enable`. Now I need to study a whole chapter about those "static". =)

Comment: Actually, for the most part you should just ignore "static" units. They're meant to be used by the Linux distribution, for services they want to *always* start and not allow the administrator to control them... In practice, you'll always want to use non-static units, so always include an `[Install]` section is a good advice.

Comment: @anatolytechtonik Rephrased the answer to give emphasis on the fact you'll most likely always want to include an `[Install]` section. You should not really care about static units... Except perhaps to know they exist and they are normal if you bump into one...

Comment: So, in the end `[Install]` section is obligatory for `.service`s that I want to autostart?

Comment: Well, the `[Install]` section is obligatory for `.service`s that you want to manage with `systemctl enable`. I'd argue that in 99% of cases, you want to be able to manage your `.service`s with `systemctl enable`. If you're curious, there's also this other thing called "static" units, which will also auto-start on boot, but they don't have an `[Install]` section (and can't be managed with `systemctl disable`), but that feature is meant to be used by Linux distributions only, so you should really not care about it, and always include an `[Install]` section. :-)

Comment: Sorry, I'm just trying to be very accurate here... Saying that `[Install]` is obligatory is not really accurate... But for all you care about, it might as well be obligatory. You most likely want to include it in every unit you write.

Comment: I edited you answer with all info I wanted to know, but was afraid to ask. Please, check that I did't misguide anyone. I thought that symlinking is too low level detail until I understand high level logic, so I omitted it until the very end.

Comment: @anatolytechtonik I reviewed your edits, moved things around a little bit and approved it. One point is that "static" units are not as opposed to "service" units. You can have units of any kind ("service", "target", "socket", "path") that are "static", so it's an orthogonal concept. Thanks for your edit, your suggestions were great. Cheers!